# notEqualTo in where cluase in zend

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, where-clause

I am trying to fetch all rows from mysql table where two column values are not equal in zend 
So I tried using 
`where->notEqualTo('table.column1','table.column2')` 
but the rhs is being parsed as a value. 
How can I fetch the rows with unequal values in two columns ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why don't you add this condition in the join criteria? `->join('table2', 'table1.column != table2.column', ['columns','you','need','from','table2'])`

Comment: I don't have two tables. I want to retrieve rows from a single table where the column1 value is not equal to column2 value

Comment: My bad, I somehow read `table1.column` instead of `table.column` ^^

Comment: okay, If I use self join then I will end up in  one to many relationship. That will be fetching me n*n rows